# Laravel Vue web-notification component errors

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to display Notification Bar from component vue to layout/app.blade but errors occures in the console.

> [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined"

and,

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined

my app.js is like below.

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
window._ = require('lodash');
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

Vue.component('estate', require('./components/EstateNotification.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        estates: '',
    },
    created(){
      if (window.Laravel.userId){
          axios.post('/notification/estate/notification').then(response => {
              this.estates = response.data;
              console.log(response.data)
          });

          Echo.private('App.User.'+ window.Laravel.userId).notification((response) => {
              data = {"data":response};
              this.estates.push(data);
              console.log(response);
          });
      }
    }
});
```

In my route:

```
Route::post('/notification/estate/notification', 'EstateController@notification');
```

Controller:

```
public function notification()
    {
        return auth()->user()->unreadNotifications;
    }
```

But I couldn't figure it, why is userId being undefined? where am I doing wrong? Really thanks for any help!

Comment: It means that `window.Laravel` is null.  Did you output in blade `<script>window.Laravel = {!! json_encode(some object with userId) !!}</script>`?  This is just your first error.  I see more errors in your code.  Like `v-for="estate in estates"` not what you have, which is reversed.

Comment: actually, I didn't i am a bit new in vue. but also it can't be null. am I making some syntax mistake?

Comment: You did this`if (window.Laravel.userId)`, it's not really vue, it's javascript.  It expect that there is a global variable called `Laravel` which has to come from somewhere.  You have to output it from server in `blade`.

Comment: I fixed template, and re-designed controller and route; but still getting undefined userId. I updated the codes in question. @Noogen

Answer (score 0):

Try this in app.blade :

```
<div id ="app">
    <estate v-bind:estates="estates"></estate>
</div>




const app = new Vue({
       el: '#app'  //this ID
   });
```